# Trying to build an SQL Server query with a specific output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two main tables with a joining table. One table has all of the main records, the second table has categories that the main records would be associated with. the link table. The joining table has entries with IDs from both the categories, and the main records, and it builds associations (main record id 2, to category id 245 as an example)

I am trying to build a query that outputs all of the main records, with all of the categories for each row of the main records, as some rows can have many categories.

What I would love it to do is output them in a delimited fashion so that I can keep it to one row per main record. Right now the best I seem to be able to do is a row for each category that main item has. example of what I want (highly simplified).

```
ID  | Name  | Category 
-------------------------------------
2   | thing | shiny,special,explosive
```

What I get now is:

```
ID  | Name  | Category
-------------------------
2   | thing | shiny
2   | thing | special
2   | thing | explosive
```

etc.

Here is my current query in it's state - the reason there are so many columns being selected is there is many columns in the table, and I only need a few shown.

```
SELECT Attractions.ID
     , Attractions.HotelName
     , Attractions.Enabled
     , Attractions.HotelAddress1
     , Attractions.HotelAddress2
     , Attractions.City
     , Attractions.Prov
     , Attractions.Country
     , Attractions.PostalCode
     , Attractions.Latitude
     , Attractions.Longitude
     , Attractions.Ratings
     , Attractions.Phone
     , Attractions.Fax
     , Attractions.TollFree
     , Attractions.Email
     , Attractions.Website
     , Attractions.ShowInSearch
     , Attractions.MoreInfoCounter
     , Attractions.ContactPerson
     , Attractions.ContactPersonFirst
     , Attractions.ContactPersonLast
     , Attractions.Notes
     , Attractions.SponsorID
     , Attraction_Sub_Types.Name
FROM
  dbo.Attractions_Attraction_Sub_Types_Link
  INNER JOIN dbo.Attractions
    ON Attractions_Attraction_Sub_Types_Link.AttractionID = Attractions.ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Attraction_Sub_Types
    ON Attractions_Attraction_Sub_Types_Link.Sub_TypeID = Attraction_Sub_Types.ID
WHERE
  Attractions.ShowInSearch = 1
ORDER BY
  Attractions.ID
```

I had at first experimented with sub queries but I could never get one to validate or even where to start so I abandoned that.

Comment: Have you tried left outer joins instead?

Comment: Do you want a comma delimited column, or you are just asking for suggestions to get one category per main record?

Comment: @ZeRaTuL_jF I want a comma delimited column.

Comment: You can use the STUFF function.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I have never tried those before

Comment: http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/

Comment: I have not looked at the STUFF function before, fascinating.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `COALESCE` function. Try something like:

```
DECLARE @Category VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Category = COALESCE(@Category + ', ', '') + Category
FROM categories_table
WHERE Category IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

THis is a sample of how to do this:

```
select 'test' as Test, 1 as Item 
into #test 
union select 'test2', 2 
union select 'test', 3 
union select NUll, 4 
union select 'test', 5 

select t2.test, STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + cast(t1.Item as varchar (10) )
        FROM #test t1 where t2.test = t1.test 
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
     from #test t2
     group by t2.test
```

Comment: I apologize for my thickheadedness, However my experience in SQL is not where it could be and I don't really understand how this query would work in my instance.

Comment: This is what you were shooting for, a sub query for the categories, separated by a comma.